# PayPal basics with Javascript and Classic ASP

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic, paypal

I am having a hard time getting started here. I have never used the PayPal API, and I can't seem to get a grasp of what direction I should be taking. The wealth of information is overwhelming.

I have an existing application built in a Software As a Service architecture. Basically, this particular part of the application is being used for making reservations. We have an existing process and we are trying to add PayPal integration allow users to pay deposits on these reservations.

I have been tinkering by copying code from another site that we have created. The developer that handled it has since moved on, so I cannot pick his brain. I have the application working in a basic person to person payment kind of scheme. The buyer receives an email receipt and the merchant also receives notification via email. I need to get some kind of notice back to my application that the payment was received and processed.

Earlier I mentioned the SAAS architecture. Where that comes into play is the registration software is for a specific business. Multiple businesses have access to their own personalized version of the registration package. I need to see about having the API calls use the PayPal credentials for each business instead of my account.

As far as the environment goes, I am using Classic ASP (not by my choice) for server side, and JQuery on client side. Can someone please point me in the right direction? I am not sure if I should use the classic API or the REST API.

Here is a sample of what I am currently using that sends notifications via email:

```
    <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Deposit for event at <%= SiteInfo.Name %>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<%= EncodeId(myEvent.EventId) %>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<%= SiteInfo.VantoraUrl %>/registration/testpayment.asp" />
        <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<%= SiteInfo.Url %>/registration/paymentcancelled.asp?id=<%= EncodeId(myEvent.EventId) %>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<%= Settings(SETTING_PAYMENT_PAYPALADDRESS) %>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0" />
        <input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="Return to <%= SiteInfo.Name %>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="<%= GetCurrencyValue() %>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<%= GetDepositAmount() %>" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that you're looking for some kind of notification back, have you looked into Instant Payment Notification (IPN)? IPN is a post sent out to a script after a transaction completes. 
It seems to be exactly what you're after.

In your code you can add this extra line to set your IPN URL:

```
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="domain.com/notify.php" />
```

IPN code samples: 
https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples

Documentation:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/

Comment: does this work when the merchant is using a personal account?

Comment: It looks like that works fine with personal accounts. Thanks for your help.